# Redirect Anchor from URL to specify Onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On our website, we have a page where we have 5 images that are buttons. When you click each button, more detailed information appears using the onclick function.

What we would like to do is pull the anchor information from the URL `www.example.com#program` and then use that anchor to specify which onload we want to load.

So in theory, `www.example.com#program` would execute this:

```
<img src="program.png" width="159" height="115"

   onload=
    "ShowHide('ACE', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('program', 'visible');
     ShowHide('ACE2', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('ACE3', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('ACE4', 'hidden'); "/>
```

And `www.example.com#ACE` would execute this:

```
<img src="ACE.png" width="159" height="115"

   onload=
    "ShowHide('ACE', 'visible');
     ShowHide('program', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('ACE2', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('ACE3', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('ACE4', 'hidden'); "/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you watch for changes to the hash you can do this more dynamically:

```
var sections = ['ACE', 'program', 'ACE2', 'ACE3', 'ACE4'];

window.onhashchange = function(evt) {
   var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
   // iterate sections and make section at location.hash visible
   sections.forEach(function(section) {
      var visibility = 'hidden';
      if(section === hash) {
         visibility = 'visible';
      }
      ShowHide(section, visibility);
   });
};
```

You can view a demonstration of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/a41j5ed7/, open up the console to see which item is visible and which are hidden.

Since you already have an onclick setup for each image button, you will need to update the hash when the user clicks the button. You didn't post the code that handles the image button clicks, but it will be something like:

```
imageButton.onclick = function() {
   // whatever you are currently doing when the user clicks the image button
   location.hash = 'ACE'; // or whichever button they clicked
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect! What I had to do is add the scrolltop function because it would jump down on the page.

Comment: Well it kind of works. When I am on the page and I manually enter in the hash 'www.example.com#ACE' it loads perfect. When I enter the page say from a social media post with the same URL, it doesn't load.

Comment: You will need to call `location.hash = 'ACE'`, etc. in your button onclick to update the hash

Comment: Does that go inside onclick like this: 
`<img src="ACE.png" width="159" height="115"

   onload="
     location.hash = 'ACE'
     ShowHide('ACE', 'visible');
     ShowHide('program', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('ACE2', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('ACE3', 'hidden');
     ShowHide('ACE4', 'hidden'); "/>`

Comment: I've updated my answer, you said you already have an onclick handler setup for your image buttons, you will need to update the location hash in each click handler, the other code I posted should be placed outside of any onclick handlers.

Comment: I wonder if I placed the script in the wrong place. Everything works fine when I am on the page. Everything works fine until I direct someone to the page with the url `www.example.com#ACE`

The hash changes properly when I click on the image, in .inc shows up correctly via onclick, it is just that initial step of the entering the URL where the onload does not work.